# Retrieve data from Room using Column Value - Room

Tags: android, android-room, viewmodel

I have two tables in my Room DB - Events and Notes. For each event I have displayed in the RecycleView - I have a link to launch a note for that event. On first click - Note is created. On the second time the note is clicked, I would like to retrieve the previous note and then edit. Also, I am using the same activity to already edit/create new notes by passing on appropriate values, which works but uses parcelized note.

For editing an existing event Note - I am sending across the event ID (which is also stored in the Note table - not as a Foreign key) using the putExtra method. DB structure below (assocId refers to eventId)

ViewModel

```
    fun setNotesByAssocEventId(assocEventId: String): Note {
    return dao.getByAssocEventId(assocEventId)
}
```

DAO

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE assocEventId = :assocEventId")
    fun getByAssocEventId(assocEventId: String): Note
```

NoteEntity

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
        @Parcelize
data class Note(
    //PrimaryKey annotation to declare primary key with auto increment value
    //ColumnInfo annotation to specify the column's name
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "assocEventId") var assocEventId: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") var title: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "label") var label: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date") var date: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "time") var time: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "updatedDate") var updatedDate: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "updatedTime") var updatedTime: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "body") var body: String = ""
) : Parcelable
```

I am using the below code to edit/create new notes. While I am able to create/Edit notes. I am unable to retrieve a node for a particular event using the eventId. One of the errors I am getting is Note object has not been initialized when I am assigning the note object returned from the ViewModel. What could be the issue?

assocID is the event ID obtained using putExtra and the corresponding event note is to be retrieved...

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityEditNoteBinding
private lateinit var notesViewModel: NotesViewModel
private lateinit var note: Note
private var assocId: String? = ""
private var isUpdate = false
private val dateChange = DateChange()

var refUsers: DatabaseReference? = null
var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityEditNoteBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    assocId = intent.getStringExtra("eventId").toString()

    initView()
    initListener()
}

private fun initView() {

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    initViewModel()

    if (assocId != null) {
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editNote).text = "Edit Event Note"
        Toast.makeText(this, "EvetnId received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        isUpdate = true
        binding.editNoteDelete.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        notesViewModel.getNotes()
        note = notesViewModel.setNotesByAssocEventId("%${assocId}%")
        binding.editTextTitle.setText(note.title)
        binding.editTextBody.setText(note.body)
        binding.editTextTitle.setSelection(note.title.length)

        //set spinner position
        val compareValue = note.label
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.NoteSpinnerVals,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        )

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        binding.spLabel.adapter = adapter
        val spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(compareValue)
        binding.spLabel.setSelection(spinnerPosition)

    }

}

private fun initViewModel() {
    notesViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(NotesViewModel::class.java)
}


private fun initListener() {
  //  binding.editNoteBack.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.editNoteSave.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.editNoteDelete.setOnClickListener(this)
}

private fun deleteNote(note: Note) {
    notesViewModel.deleteNote(note)
    Toast.makeText(this@EditNote, "Note removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

private fun showDialog() {

    AwesomeDialog.build(this)
        .position(AwesomeDialog.POSITIONS.CENTER)
        .title("Delete the note?")
        .icon(R.drawable.ic_delete_black)
        .background(R.drawable.background_dialog)
        .onPositive(
            "Yes, delete",
            buttonBackgroundColor = R.drawable.button_bg,
            textColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)
        ) {
            deleteNote(note)
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
        .onNegative(
            "Cancel",
            buttonBackgroundColor = R.drawable.button_bg,
            textColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)
        ) {

        }

}
```

Code of the ViewModel

```
    class NotesViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val context = getApplication<Application>().applicationContext
    private val listNotes = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Note>>()
    private var dao: NoteDao

    init {
        val database = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context)
        dao = database.getNoteDao()
    }

    fun setNotes() {
        val listItems = arrayListOf<Note>()

        listItems.addAll(dao.getAll())
        listNotes.postValue(listItems)
    }

    fun setNotesByType(label: String) {
        val listItems = arrayListOf<Note>()

        listItems.addAll(dao.getByLabel(label))
        listNotes.postValue(listItems)
    }

    fun setNotesByTitle(title: String) {
        val listItems = arrayListOf<Note>()

        listItems.addAll(dao.getByTitle(title))
        listNotes.postValue(listItems)
    }

    fun setNotesByAssocEventId(assocEventId: String): Note {
        return dao.getByAssocEventId(assocEventId)
    }

    fun insertNote(note: Note) {
        dao.insert(note)
    }

    fun updateNote(note: Note) {
        dao.update(note)
    }

    fun deleteNote(note: Note) {
        dao.delete(note)
    }

    fun getNotes(): LiveData<ArrayList<Note>> {
        return listNotes
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add your code of viewmodel

Comment: Hi Rahat, I have added the ViewModel code...

Comment: Here you get null `note = notesViewModel.setNotesByAssocEventId("%${assocId}%")`??

Comment: yes, thats where I get null

Comment: why you are using `%` in `"%${assocId}%"`

Comment: I was trying to see if that worked, same issue without % and $..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227991/discussion-between-madhall-and-rahat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method in the DAO need to be changed a little

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE assocEventId = :assocEventId")
    fun getByAssocEventId(assocEventId: String): Note
```

should be

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE assocEventId LIKE :assocEventId")
    fun getByAssocEventId(assocEventId: String): LiveData<List<Note>>
```

In order to support wild character search, `"%${assocId}%"`, LIKE keyword.

To get one Note only

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE assocEventId LIKE :assocEventId LIMIT 1")
    fun getByAssocEventId(assocEventId: String): LiveData<Note>
```

in view model

```
fun setNotesByAssocEventId(assocEventId: String): LiveData<Note>{
     return dao.getByAssocEventId(assocEventId)
   }
```

in the activity

```
notesViewModel.setNotesByAssocEventId("%${assocId}%").observe(this, {
   if(it!=null){
     //if you using for single note only
   }

   //if(it.isNotEmpty()){
     //if you using for list
   //}
})
```